# Resolve java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, exception, java-stream, concurrentmodification

as the title suggests,
I need to fix this exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null.
Below the code that goes into error:

```
Map<String, List<Note>> noteByCod = notes.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Note::getCod));
noteByCod.forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach(note -> {
       if (!note.getVer() || !StringUtils.isEmpty(note.getError())) {
                noteByCod.remove(k);
       }
}));
```

the problem is that it is not possible to modify the collection you are iterating on, in this case how would you solve?

Comment: Even simpler `noteByCod.values().removeIf(v -> v.stream().anyMatch(note -> !note.getVer() || !StringUtils.isEmpty(note.getError())));` And when you clean up your API and make a definite decision whether an error free note should return `null` or an empty string from `getError()`, you can get rid of `StringUtils.isEmpty` and use either `getError() != null` or `!getError().isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite this to use an old-fashioned `Iterator` over the entry set. `Iterator` has a `remove` method that allows the last-returned object to be removed:

```
Map<String, List<Note>> noteByCod = ...;
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, List<Note>> it = noteByCode.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  if (it.next().getValue().stream().anyMatch(
        note -> !note.getVer() || !StringUtils.isEmpty(note.getError()))) {
    it.remove();
  }
}));
```

Comment: The Stream way would require to collect a list of notes to remove, so this is definitely a more direct, efficient solution. If not the noteByCode is redone.

Comment: @EngineerTop: removeIf is actually a nicer solution, well done. If you find a solution, you can and should post it as an answer, please don't edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, I finally solved it like this:

```
Map<String, List<Note>> noteByCod = notes.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Note::getCod));
noteByCod.values().removeIf(v -> v.stream().anyMatch(note -> !note.getVer() || !StringUtils.isEmpty(note.getError())));
```

Comment: Good job ! indeed